# Visual difference between browsers

Tags: html, css

Why do I get different menues!? I dont want it to look like it does in Firefox, but despite that I change in the CSS, I can't get it perfect. Any ideas what I can do to solve this?

Menu in Firefox: It's the overlapping part of the bottom of the blue area that I want to get rid off.

[image: image of a menu]

Menu i Chrome, Safari and IE:

[image: Image of menu in Chrome]

CSS:

```
.menuContainer
{
height: 60px;
width: 100%;
background: #C9C9C9;
}

.mainMenu
{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 60%;
}

.mainMenu nav
{
margin: 15px 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
height: 40px;
float: left;
background: #C9C9C9;
}

.mainMenu nav ul
{
list-style: none;
padding-left:  0px;
margin: 0;
}

.mainMenu nav ul li
{
float: left;
display: inline;
}

.mainMenu nav ul li a
{
color: #fff;
display: inline;
padding: 19px 10px 19px 10px;
margin: 0 20px 0 0;
font-family: 'Montserrat',serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 700;
}

/* highlight menu alt 1 */ 
body#hem a#hem-link,
body#karta a#karta-link,
body#byggnad a#byggnad-link,
body#byggnader a#byggnader-link,
body#tips a#tips-link,
body#info a#info-link,
body#omguiden a#omguiden-link,
body#kopenhamn a#kopenhamn-link {
background: #00B4FF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menuContainer">
<div class="mainMenu">
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a  id="hem-link" href="?p=hem">Hem</a></li>
<li><a  id="kopenhamn-link" href="?p=kopenhamn">Köpenhamn</a></li>
<li><a  id="karta-link" href="?p=karta">Karta</a></li>
<li><a  id="byggnader-link" href="?p=byggnader">Bilder</a></li>
<li><a  id="tips-link" href="?p=tips">Tips</a></li>
<li><a  id="omguiden-link" href="?p=om-guiden">Om guiden</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please also provide the HTML. Don't make us guess.

Comment: I tried but I could not paste it like "HTML" code! How do I do?

Comment: paste it in, then highlight it and click the { } button. or make a js fiddle

Comment: maybe your chrome is old version and your firefox is earlier ! :D

Comment: No, latest version of all

Comment: please make a js fiddle, www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Looks like you haven't posted everything, because I cannot even reproduce the style: http://jsfiddle.net/yuE9Y/.

Comment: I guess it's to complicated to upload it to jsfiddle when it's a framework made in PHP code!?

Comment: I added some more code. I hope this could help?

Comment: It's true that jsFiddle doesn't do PHP, but you should paste the generated HTML in anyway. The browsers don't care what the server side looks like anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Dont rely on default from imported fonts - size and line-height may not not be the same as 'web-safe' fonts

Allways sæt value of line-height - browsers renders line-height differently. Maybe only by a few pixels, but could be an issue

```
.mainMenu nav ul li a  {
line-height: 1.2;
color: #fff;
padding: 19px 10px 19px 10px;
margin: 0 20px 0 0;
font-family: 'Montserrat',serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Would it be better to use arial or verdana fonts?

Comment: Your solution didn't work, I got a line above instead

Comment: Has to do with adressing the line-height - looks the same crossbrowser now?

Comment: No need for display: inline I guess!?

Comment: Anyway - add a height for li and line-height in li a and you should be ok

Comment: Now it's fine with all browser, but not IE ! :(